# where can I find mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb.asc

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, gnupg, apt

I have issue with install `mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb` in `Debian 9` but I have apt-key issue.

I find that I can use `Signature Checking Using GnuPG` I find the `PGP SIGNATURE` but i can't find the `mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb.asc` how can I find it to do `gpg --verify package_name.asc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the newest MySQL apt repository `mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb`. You can download the `file.asc` from [MySQL webpage](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) by clicking on the Signature, copy the PGP key and save it under  `mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb.asc`: here is the signature:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=CoWc
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```